# Book with parallel universes being taken over by an evil presence

Tags: story-identification, parallel-universe

It would have been published around 2012.

It's about a guy taking a girl with him to parallel universes.  The universes are empty/dangerous because there is an evil presence there; something like big black winged animals (that smell foul).

The villain is using that force to take over this universe, and eventually becomes the foul-smelling 'bird'.

The one thing I remember specifically about the book was that when they jumped universes, they had to eat a ton of calories.  I think he ate multiple orders of pancakes in a restaurant the first time he was explaining to the girl that they had to go.

Comment: "Foul-smelling bird" I see what you did there. :)